# php Class not working functions

Tags: php, mysql, function, class

I got some strange problems. Using my class i connecting to mysql, connection is successful but when i call a function its not works. Im using my own error handler and if i got in php some error on this line it using exit; i have used echo before calling function and after page is not killing (it means that php work successful) mysql query i have checked its works too but when im using return 'some text'; its not returning. any suggestions why function is not working?

my class:

```
<?php
include('../config.php');
include('../chat_error_handler.php');

class Chat {
    private $mysqli;
    var $con;

    //Constructor open db conn
    function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
    }

    //destructor close db conn
    function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }

    public function postNewMessage($user_name, $message, $color, $room_id) {
        $user_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($user_name);
        $message = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($message);
        $color = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($color);
        $room_id = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($room_id);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO chat (posted_on, account, message, color, room_id)' .
        ' VALUES (NOW(), "'.$user_name.'", "'.$message.'", "'.$color.'", "'. $room_id .'")';
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
        return 'Pranesimas';
        $result->close();
    }
```

My php im using to debug:

```
<?php
include('core/chat.class.php');
include('chat_error_handler.php');
$chat = new Chat();
$message = 'testas';
echo $message.'<br/>';
$chat->postNewMessage('testing', $message, '#000000', 1);
echo '<br/>'.$message;
?>
```

Comment: <cringe> Using MySQLi, but still escaping fields and building the query by injection

Comment: what are the errors you are receiving ? if errors turned up

Comment: What do you mean by "the function doesn't work". What do you expect to happen and what exactly happens? Also having anything after the `return` statement in a function isn't very useful.

Comment: error allways turned up and its returns nothing. this function must insert message into table and return this message back. but nothing happens and no errors i can catch.

Comment: `"'.$color.'`, should be `"'. $color .'"` - regardless, if an MySQL insert isn't working, always attempt to get the Query String and try yourself in PHPMyAdmin or your MySQL Command line, then you'll see errors

Comment: thanks fix this :), but not working still

Comment: Well, I think you've encased the variables incorrectly, as it's much better to insert with `'` instead of `"` for strings into MySQL, I'll add an answer in a bit =)

Comment: I have tried this :) its still not work but i thing you right i should use `'` instead of `"`

Comment: I'm including my class ant then using this line to initiate `$chat = new Chat();` and calling function with `$chat->postNewMessage('testing', $message, '#000000', 1);` with variables in ()

Comment: What are the actual values of the variables $user_name, $message, $color and $room_id after escaping? I guess the problem lays in the $room_id. You should not put apostrohpes around an integer in the actual query (even though mysql is very forgiving)

Comment: Another thought it that it could be in your error-handler. Try to comment that file out and see what happens.

Comment: room_id is a string and in my table it's nvarchar

Comment: @Mik, ok - but you're sending an integer in the function call? (1) Shouldn't it be like $chat->postNewMessage('testing', $message, '#000000', '1'); then?

Comment: i have tried to comment error_handler but it still not returning, the 2nd answer helped me with inserting :)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld how about my insert im using there `''` isnt there there integer is converting?

Comment: It wasn't the actual issue, you've got a good explaination by MackieeE :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function postNewMessage($user_name, $message, $color, $room_id) {

    $user_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($user_name);
    $message = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($message);
    $color = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($color);
    $room_id = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($room_id);

    $query = 
       "INSERT INTO 
            chat ( posted_on, 
                   account, 
                   message, 
                   color, 
                   room_id )
        VALUES ( NOW(), 
                 '". $user_name ."', 
                 '". $message ."', 
                 '". $color ."', 
                 '". $room_id ."' )";

    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

    if ( $result ) {
        return 'Pranesimas'; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i got error in my destructor but when i have removed it it work only return now not working. Can you explain what the point of problem was?

Comment: I do believe the only thing that was wrong with your code was the SQL Query, it was being escaped by `"` rather than single quotations.

Comment: Secondly, `$result->close()` might be throwing an error, thus it's not returning correctly. As you'd use `$result->close()` if it were in a loop normally (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

About `'var'` in PHP5 and upper.
It's for declaring class member variables in PHP4, and is no longer needed. It will work in PHP5, but will raise an `E_STRICT` warning in PHP from version `5.0.0` up to version `5.1.2`, as of which it has been deprecated.

**UPDATE:**

```
public function postNewMessage($user_name, $message, $color, $room_id) {
        return 'Pranesimas1';
        $user_name = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($user_name);
        $message = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($message);
        $color = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($color);
        return 'Pranesimas2';
        $room_id = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($room_id);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO chat (posted_on, account, message, color, room_id)' .
        ' VALUES (NOW(), "'.$user_name.'", "'.$message.'", "'.$color.', "'. $room_id .'")';
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);
        return 'Pranesimas';
        $result->close();
    }
```

Try add return step by step for detect where is problem and let me know about result.

Comment: i have user this var for some testing. now i'll remove at all this var.

Comment: if return is succes delete. Trouble be there are where return not work

Comment: i dont get any return :(

Comment: maybe problem with my php configuration o etc.?